# Mayonnaise Split

Tags: sauce, mayonnaise

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making Mayo by hand , using whisk , emulsion breaks down](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12134/making-mayo-by-hand-using-whisk-emulsion-breaks-down)

Hi,I would like to know how to fix the Mayonnaise if it splits while whisking and making it with hand.

Answer (score 2):

You can do any of the following:

- Beat one egg yolk, then add it drop by drop to the mayonnaise, beating constantly.
- Whisk in a teaspoon of cold water
- Whisk a little of the curdled mayo into a tablespoon of water, then add the rest of the mayo bit by bit

Answer (score 2):

Whisk a fresh egg yolk in a separate bowl and then slowly add your existing, split, mayonaise into that egg (as you were doing with the oil).  Once that's incorporated, add any leftover oil that you have.  The trick is to do it so ridiculously slowly that you think it will never come together.  But it will :)