# Homemade mayonnaise difficulties

Tags: mayonnaise

I have been trying to make mayonnaise and have had no luck. I have tried it 4 times now, twice in a Blendtec blender following their instructions online and twice following [these](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gz0fLT_k3_U) directions . Each time the mayonnaise came out like yellow stinky soup.

I have been adding the oil very slowly, it takes about 2 minutes to add a cup. I have let my eggs warm up to room temperature for an hour. I have bought fresh eggs.

It looks so simple, but I am having no luck. Please help.

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12134/making-mayo-by-hand-using-whisk-emulsion-breaks-down

Comment: That YouTube method is bizarre, adding all the oil at once. You're saying 'eggs' - I assume you're only using the yolks, yes?

Comment: Why was it "stinky"? Even if it's not a nice mayo, it shouldn't smell bad.

Comment: For the immersion blender method, how narrow is the container you use? I use that method myself and it doesn't work at all unless the head of the blender barely fits at the bottom of the glass. And for the record that method works with whole eggs too, I don't bother separating.

Comment: this method works just fine, i think the problem the OP is running into is the blender he's using. The stick blender isn't nearly as powerful as the blendtec. I am assuming by the soup your looking at an overmixed emulsion kind of like if you were to whip cream too long and it turned to butter and forced out all of the moisture. I would try doing it by hand first with a whisk so you get the hang of what its supposed to look like.

Comment: What type of oil are you using? It isn't easy with olive oil, it works better with canola and such.

Comment: How long are you leaving the blender on for? I don't see how if you dumped all the ingredients into something as powerful as a Blentec and left it running for 3-4 minutes at max speed that it wouldn't emulsify the sauce.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try it by hand with a whisk first, rather than going straight to a blender, though a blender will work fine (though I've only done it with a standing blender, not an immersion blender)  The key I've found is the very slow addition of the oil to the beaten egg yolks.  (only yolks, no white).  You might want to taste your oil to make sure that it isn't rancid, which might be the cause of your "stinky" issue.  It does take some practice to pour the oil in slowly while you are beating the yolks, but you can add more oil at a time as your emulsion gets more stable.

I've found that it's not so hard to do by hand, and that you will get a real sense of accomplishment once you've done it.

Comment: Secure you bowl so you can use both hands - one to wisk and one to pour the oil in a thin, steady stream, while you beat the emulsion really fast. That should do the trick (the arm workout is an added bonus)

Answer (score 1):

The all-at-once, egg at the bottom, oil on top, add vinegar/lemon juice, salt - STICK BLENDER method- works fine almost every time.  Otherwise I couldn't do it.  That s..l..o..w drip method is too hard for me.